# How to force ElasticSearch to index data on particular node

Tags: configuration, routes, elasticsearch

I have 8 boxes: 4 high performance boxes with 1TB and 4 rather low performance boxes but with much bigger disk storage about 6TB. Each indexed document has "date" field and 80% of my search usecases occurs in the past two years (volume of last 2 years is about 800GB).

So, idea is following: force ElasticSearch to store documents from last 2 years on shards distributed between high performance boxes and rest of data (older than 2 years) on shards distributed between low performance boxes.

Question is: how can I configure ES cluster to achieve this?

I was reading about _routing, but I have no idea how I can adapt it for my idea?

Appreciate for your ideas/ help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think routing is the way to go. With routing you can determine which shard to go to. I would go for time based indexes, maybe per year or per month. Than configure the allocation of these indexes that you query a lot to go to the high performance machines.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I did like you proposed. I've split my cluster to two zones with separate index in each zone. I've created common alias for them, so search is fine, but I have to create regular job to move "old" data from first index to the second one. Too bad that ElasticSearch cannot do this part automatically, but it works for me anyway. Thanks for help.